# Get state of other channel

Tags: asterisk

Is it possible to get a state of another channel. For example: In my dialplan I want to know the state of channel: SIP/provider/0612345678 and it should return, INVITE or ANSWERED etc

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use function SHARED.

```
core show function SHARED 

  -= Info about function 'SHARED' =- 

[Synopsis]
Gets or sets the shared variable specified. 

[Description]
Implements a shared variable area, in which you may share variables between
channels.
The variables used in this space are separate from the general namespace
of the channel and thus ${SHARED(foo)} and ${foo}  represent two completely
different variables, despite sharing the same name.
Finally, realize that there is an inherent race between channels operating
at the same time, fiddling with each others' internal variables, which is
why this special variable namespace exists; it is to remind you that variables
in the SHARED namespace may change at any time, without warning.  You should
therefore take special care to ensure that when using the SHARED namespace,
you retrieve the variable and store it in a regular channel variable before
using it in a set of calculations (or you might be surprised by the
result).

[Syntax]
SHARED(varname[,channel])

[Arguments]
varname
    Variable name
channel
    If not specified will default to current channel. It is the complete
    channel name: 'SIP/12-abcd1234' or the prefix only 'SIP/12'.
```

For answered you have check variable DIALSTATUS